# Get Base Domain Name from Host / URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns

I have a Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku. As part of the app, I need to take a host name that has been entered and determine the base domain so we can do an automated NS lookup to find the host name's authoritative name server using Resolv.

Given the following examples entered into the app:

```
www.google.com
online.domain.com
www.somedomain.co.uk
sub.host.domain.com
```

How do I get just the base domains:

```
google.com
domain.com
somedomain.co.uk
domain.com
```

The tricky part is we can't just take the last two parts of the domain name due to international URLs.  But I don't know of any other way to get a host name stripped down to where we can find the NS record for it.  Curious about any suggestions.

Comment: Be more clear. It is hard to understand what your question is? Please provide detail where you have hosted your domain/website.

Comment: Clarified. Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku

Comment: Please follow this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: @ShyamBhimani that does not apply. The doc referenced is in regards to a domain name used in hosting the application. I am referring to take a host name as an entry and getting the base domain name from it for a DNS NS record lookup.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any easy way to do this. "co.uk" is technically a valid domain, and "example.co.uk" is a subdomain. You'll have to have a list of all endings that you consider to be the "base" domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options that I'm aware of:

1. Create a regex that matches all possible domain extensions, then exract the preceding hostname. You can find a public list for all possible domain extensions here: https://publicsuffix.org/list/.
2. Use the domainatrix gem (https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) which has a registry of all domain extensions collected from the above list:

   > > url = Domainatrix.parse("http://www.example.co.uk")
   > >     => #
   > >     url.domain
   > >     => "example"
   > >     url.public_suffix
   > >     => "co.uk"

Comment: Domainatrix looks interesting, though I do worry a bit that it hasn't been updated in over two years. Maybe not an issue with domain extensions though.

Comment: It looks like there's some difference. Comparing the list to the domainatrix uses https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix/blob/master/lib/effective_tld_names.dat to the latest one https://github.com/publicsuffix/list/blob/master/public_suffix_list.dat shows some differences.

Comment: I created a pull request to update the domain list for that repo here: https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix/pull/38. Feel free to use it if it's of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think good solution will be to use

```
    request.host
```